# Can't figure out how to write this query

Tags: mysql

I have a couple hundred records in a table and I need to get the the last 50 of them, but I need 25 males and 25 females. There is a gender column. I just can't figure out how to make that query. Can I get some help?

Comment: Please provide table structure. How to sort records?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE gender = 'M' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE gender = 'F' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25)
```

That would work I guess. For the order by ID part I assumed you have an autoincrement id column, making the **last** added records the ones with the highest ID.

Comment: Note that without an `ORDER BY`, this will probably not return _the last 50_ as requested.

Comment: Fair enough, added those to make the answer complete.

Answer (score 6):

If you need exactly 50, use a `UNION` which gets the last 25 of each.  This assumes you have some auto-incrementing `id` column which is sorted in descending order to retrieve the newest 25 of each gender.

In order to use an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` for individual components of a `UNION`, MySQL expects those components to be enclosed in `()`.

```
(SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE gender='F' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE gender='M' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25)
```

**Note**: By the way, I've used `SELECT *` here for brevity but you should *never* actually do that in a `UNION` query.  Instead, explicitly list the columns you need, and make sure they're in the same order in both parts of the `UNION`.

Like:

```
(SELECT col1, col2, coln FROM tbl WHERE gender='F'....)
UNION ALL
(SELECT col1, col2, coln FROM tbl WHERE gender='M'....)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just thought of this quickly, no guarantees.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE gender = 'male' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 25
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE gender = 'female' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 25
```

Basically, it gets the last 25 men, and the last 25 women, and combines the results together.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such concept of LAST unless you have another column which you can use to `ORDER BY`.

i suggest write 2 queries, on for males only, and another for females only.

then use an order by so there is a 'last' set.

then flip that (using `DESC`) so they are FIRST instead.

then use `LIMIT` clause to select the number you want.

then finally, `UNION` them together.

Answer (score 1):

Try using two queries, one to grab the 25 latest males and a second to grab the 25 latest females.  Then just concatenate the results.

```
SELECT * FROM males LIMIT 25 ORDER BY DESC

SELECT * FROM females LIMIT 25 ORDER BY DESC
```